# android WebView cant render my native language

Tags: java, android, webview, android-asynctask

Hello I am trying to load HTML (From String)

Here is the RSS feed (I am getting a link from there and after that HTML string from specific class ):

http://www.naec.ge/index.php?option=com_rsssyndicator&feed_id=1&format=raw

As you can see it is encoded in `utf-8`, but still I can't render it, it gives me this result: [android web view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crZGy.png)

Here are the code fragments :

```
class parseText extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
    {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params)
        {
            try {
                org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                System.out.println("hey kurwo "+doc.getElementsByClass("article-content"));
                data = doc.getElementsByClass("article-content").toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); System.out.println("jeban!!");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            System.out.println("chiken boneZZZ");
            view.loadData(data,"text/html","UTF-8");
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

}
```

Also this, I don't think there is any problem :

```
public class NewsDetails extends Activity
{
    static String url;
    WebView view;
    TextView info;
    static String data;
    String address;
    Bundle bundle;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detailed_news_layout);
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        url = bundle.getString("Link");
        view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        new parseText().execute();
    }
```

Comment: fixed :   view.loadData(data,"text/html","utf-8"); this won;t work 
            view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null); this will , easy peasy..

Comment: Not related to your question, but: why assign the result to `data` field instead of using the thread-safe return value? You could return the string instead of null, and receive it in the "s" parameter of `onPostExecute`. You must keep in mind that `doInBackground` and `onPostExecute` are not called on the same thread. Unless the `data` field is marked volatile, it might lead to synchronization issues.

Comment: I will keep that in mind , thx dude for nice response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a deal you have to use loaddatawithbaseurl instead of loadData(), here is example : this will not work `view.loadData(data,"text/html","utf-8");`
this will work :

view.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, data, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);